# Siri Shortcuts: how to use the "Get Contents of Url"? GET/POST method

Tags: html, post, get, shortcut, sirishortcuts

I'm making a shortcut. I need to get my specific news in https://news.google.com; therefore I need to log in https://accounts.google.com/signin inside the shortcut. So I need to fill in the Username and Password forms. I imagine that I need to use the command "Get Contents of Url" and a POST or GET method. How do I do this? What Request Body should I choose (JSON or Form)? What Key should I type in for my username and what Key for my password? I've got a lot to learn, but I need a place to start, so your help is very much needed. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not possible due to CSRF protection.

Comment: Your best bet would to sign in on another devise and then send cookie data.